# Angular ag-grid (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-url ... Can't read file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I've recently updated my modules from my angular 5 project and after opening it with angular-cli I'm getting following warning:

> WARNING in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.scss
>   (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-url: C:\workspace\default...\src\styles.scss:4673:7: Can't read file 'C:\workspace\default...\src\~ag-grid\src\styles\material-icons\left.svg', ignoring
>   NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-url: C:\workspace\default...\src\styles.scss:4673:7: Can't read file 'C:\workspace\default...\src\~ag-grid\src\styles\material-icons\left.svg', ignoring

I've also tried to roll back to the older versions of the modules but the warning is still there. Does anybody know how to remove the warning? The project is working fine but those warnings are anoying.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute path, instead use relative path.
Check your code, somewhere you are trying to call "left.svg" which is not available at "C:\workspace\default...\src\~ag-grid\src\styles\material-icons\left.svg".

Whereever you are calling "left.svg" put a slash (/) in front. Example:

example:'/assets/images/logo.png' where assets is located in the root under src folder